# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{3\,x^2+1}{x^2+3}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{3\,x^2+1}{x^2+3}\right)dx.$$
Could you suggest how to find a closed form for it? I am not sure if there is one, but the integrand seems simple enough, so I hope it might exist.

Comment: You should give it to a CAS such as WolframAlpha first and see if it can find a closed form.  If it can't, then probably one doesn't exist and you shouldn't waste your time on it.

Comment: @StefanSmith Mathematica can indeed find a closed form for the general indefinite integral. However, it is among the nastier closed forms I have ever seen. Asking Mathematica to simplify the expression eventually timed out. So while it is possible, it should be difficult.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Nastiest in what sense?  Lots of elementary functions, or lots of non-elementary functions?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Over a page of Gamma functions, Polylogs, and other many nonelementary functions.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the definite integral will actually converge.  Shouldn't the integrand be approximately $\ln(x)\ln(1/3)$ near $0$? Wolfram|Alpha gives a result of 0.848683 for it.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Logarithmic singularities converge, e.g. $\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln x\,dx=-1$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Oh, yeah.  Brainfart.  Thanks.

Comment: Use the fact that $\ln\frac ab=\ln a-\ln b$, to first break it up into two integrals. Then attack each one individually. It can be done, although each one has a hideously long expression, as you can easily see for yourself, by typing them both into Mathematica and/or Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Semi-automatic simplification of the result returned by _Mathematica_ gives [this expression](http://mathb.in/10825). I believe it can be simplified further using some dilogarithm identities. Meanwhile, I still hope to find a completely manual approach to this integral.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My calculation shows that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x}{x^{2} + 1} \log \left( \frac{t^{2}x^{2} + 1}{x^{2} + t^{2}} \right) \, dx = - \pi \chi_{2} \left( \frac{1 - t}{1 + t} \right), \tag{1} $$

where $\chi_{2}$ stands for the [Legendre chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function). I will post a detailed solution later, but I should note that the idea is very simple: denote this integral as $I(t)$ and differentiate it to obtain

$$ I'(t) = -\frac{\pi \log t}{1 - t^{2}}. $$

Restricting $|t| < 1$ temporarily, this gives

$$ I(t) = I(0) + \int_{0}^{t} I'(s) \, ds = -\pi \left\{ \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} + \log t \operatorname{artanh} t - \chi_{2}(t) \right\}. $$

Then $\text{(1)}$ restricted to $|t| < 1$ follows from the following identity:

$$ \chi_{2}\left( \frac{1-t}{1+t} \right) + \chi_{2}(t) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} + \log t \operatorname{artanh} t. $$

Then the equality for the general $t$ follows by analytic continuation. Here is a Mathematica code for testing this:

```
LegendreChi[n_, z_] := z/2^n LerchPhi[z^2, n, 1/2];

t = Sqrt[3];
NIntegrate[(Log[x] Log[(t^2 x^2 + 1)/(x^2 + t^2)])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 1},
    WorkingPrecision -> 100]
N[-Pi LegendreChi[2, (1 - t)/(1 + t)], 100]
Clear[t];
```

Comment: This also can be derived from your [earlier result](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/562492/19661), by giving imaginary values to $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Damn, I tried the same thing but only with $t$s, not $t^2$... I'm slowly learning from you guys anyway.

Comment: Wait, $|t|<0$... is this a typo?

Comment: @BennettGardiner, I fixed it :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you obtained the expression for $I'(t)$?

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
\ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> Note that
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{\infty}^{1}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x}^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3/x^{2} + 1 \over 1/x^{2} + 3}
> \,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{such that}\
> \begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
> \quad\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
> =\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x\quad
> \\ \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{Hereafter, we'll use repeatedly the well known result}\
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x = 0.
> \\&\mbox{It's trivially shown by splitting the integral in two integrals over}\ \pars{0,1}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{0,\infty}.
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
\ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
\int_{3}^{^{1}/_{3}}{\dd t \over t + x^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{3}^{^{1}/_{3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}
\pars{{1 \over x^{2} + 1} - {1 \over x^{2} + t}}\,{1 \over t - 1}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\int_{3}^{^{1}/_{3}}{1 \over t - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + t}\,\dd x\,\dd t
=-\,\half\int_{3}^{^{1}/_{3}}{1 \over t - 1}\,{1 \over \root{t}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{\root{t}x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 4}\int_{3}^{^{1}/_{3}}
{\ln\pars{\root{t}} \over \pars{t - 1}\root{t}}\,\dd t
=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{\root{3}}^{1/\root{3}}{\ln\pars{t} \over t^{2} - 1}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\bracks{\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}
{\ln\pars{t} \over t^{2} - 1}\,\dd t
-\int_{\root{3}}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over t^{2} - 1}\,\dd t}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\bracks{\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}
{\ln\pars{t} \over t^{2} - 1}\,\dd t
-\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1/t} \over 1/t^{2} - 1}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}}
\end{align}

> The original integral is reduced to:
>   $$
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
> =-\pi\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t
> $$

Then,
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
\ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
-{\pi \over 2}\int_{1/\root{3}}^{1}{\ln\pars{t} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1 - 1/\root{3}}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
+{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1/\root{3}}^{-1}{\ln\pars{-t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1 - 1/\root{3}}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
-{\pi \over 2}\bracks{\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
\ln\pars{1 - t}\ln\pars{-t}}_{-1/\root{3}}^{-1}
+{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1/\root{3}}^{-1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 2}\bracks{%
> \half\,\ln\pars{3}\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over \root{3}}}
> +\int_{0}^{1 - 1/\root{3}}\!\!\!{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
> +\int^{-1/\root{3}}_{-1}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}
> \end{align}

However, with $\ds{a < b < 1}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t&
=-\int_{a}^{b}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
=-\int_{a}^{b}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
={\rm Li}_{2}\pars{a} - {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{b}
\end{align}
where $\ds{{\rm Li}_{\rm s}\pars{z}}$ is a [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Hereafter, we'll use well known properties of them as reported in the cited link.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,
> \ln\pars{3x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{\pi \over 2}\left\lbrack%
> \half\,\ln\pars{3}\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over \root{3}}}
> -{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 - {1 \over \root{3}}}\right.}
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=-\,{\pi \over 2}\bracks{}}\color{#66f}{\large%
> \left.\mbox{}+\
> \underbrace{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-1}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 12}}}}\
> -\ {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over \root{3}}}
> \right\rbrack} \approx 0.8487
> \end{align}