# Closed form for ${_4F_3}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\tfrac12\right)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find the closed form expression for
$${_4F_3}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\tfrac12\right).$$
I encountered this expression when evaluating the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx.$$
I tried utilizing the [series representation of the generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Notation) Pochhammer symbol and applying Legendre duplication, which left me with the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{8^n(2n+1)^3}.$$
Using Mathematica, it can be approximated to be
$${_4F_3}\!\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12\\\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\tfrac12\right) \approx 1.01015469252627.$$

I have reason to believe that the closed form may contain the [inverse tangent integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral), as the hypergeometric function is similar to [@Cleo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595389/integral-large-int-0-pi-2-arctan2-left-frac-sin-x-sqrt3-cos-x-ri/1595449#1595449). Are there any neat properties
of the $_4F_3$ hypergeometric function that can be exploited in order to obtain the closed form result?

Comment: check out @Vladimir Reshetnikov's comment on my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1438525/219995

Comment: @Noam Shalev - nospoon Thank you so much! I have reduced it down to $\frac{\pi ^3}{192 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{i \text{Li}_3(1-i)-i \text{Li}_3(1+i)}{2 \sqrt{2}}$. However, I am wondering if there is a way to remove the imaginary numbers the way Cleo did in her answer

Comment: Simpler is: $\frac{\pi ^3}{192 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\Im(\text{Li}_3(1+i))}{\sqrt{2}}$