# Finding $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan\left(\sin x\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan\left(\sin x\right)dx$$

I try to solve it, but failed. Who can help me to find it?

I encountered this integral when trying to solve $\displaystyle{\int_0^\pi\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}\,dx}$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan%28sin%28x%29%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2) chokes on this, and its [simplification of $\text{arctan}(\sin x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+arctan%28sin%28x%29%29) doesn't help much either.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Mathematica says $$\frac{1}{8} \left(\pi ^2-4 \sinh ^{-1}(1)^2\right)$$

Comment: To the OP, where did you encounter this problem? E.g. math contest, calculus text or other? It's not idle curiosity- knowing the source often gives an indication of the expected level of technical knowledge required to solve it.

Comment: I encounter it when trying to solve a integral"Integrate[x*Cos[x]/(1+(Sin[x])^2),{x,0,Pi}]@Deepak"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855517/evaluating-a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficient-in-denominator

Comment: Thank you for your reminding@Pranav Arora

Comment: Please reopen this question. The path from the integral to the sum is not given in "[the original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/855517)"; it is only *mentioned* in a later edit. I don't think that this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @robjohn I voted to open!

Comment: You may consider [this result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555882/integral-int-01-frac-arctan2x-sqrt1-x2-mathrm-dx/562492#562492) as well.

Comment: By the way, if you want, write **\mathrm dx** to generate $\mathrm dx$ as opposed to $dx$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Actually I didn't post my answer as I was unable to continue it where I left but after Pranav provided link I'm posting it

$$\sin x=u\iff \frac{\,\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\,\mathrm dx$$

$$\int_0^{{\pi/2}}\arctan\left(\sin x\right)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{1}\frac{\arctan(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du$$

Now consider parametric integral
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^{1}\frac{\arctan(\alpha t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
I'(\alpha)&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{(1+\alpha^{2}t^{2})\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \,\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{1+\alpha^{2}}} \text{artanh} \left[ \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^{2}}} \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{1+\alpha^{2}}} \text{arsinh}(\alpha) .\end{align}$$
Now for further process [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855517/evaluating-a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficient-in-denominator)

Comment: $\text{arcsinh}'a=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$ for the same reason that $\arcsin'x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Why repeat RV's answer?

Comment: Awesome!Your answer make me clearly understand. Thank you very much!@Integrator

Comment: Your answer shows how to get from the current question to the supposed "original". I don't think this question should be closed since your part of the answer is not covered in the "original" question.

Comment: I have added part of my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1052675). It offers an alternate approach to evaluating $\int_0^1\frac1{\alpha\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\mathrm{arcsinh}(\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}\alpha$.

Comment: @robjohn That's nice, Should I link to your answer? Because copying someone's answer is not okay.

Comment: @Integrator: You've already linked to that question, and I believe both Random Variable's answer and mine show how to evaluate that integral. That should be enough.

Answer (score 12):

Integrating by parts, we get
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{2k}{2k+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k-1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, by induction, we have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{2^k\,k!}{(2k+1)!!}\tag{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\frac{2^k\,k!}{(2k+1)!!}\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: use the series for $\arctan(x)$
$\text{(3b)}$: use $(2)$
$\text{(3c)}$: rewrite $\text{(3b)}$ using central binomial coefficients

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1052675), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{(2n+1)^2\binom{2n}{n}}
=\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac12\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac12\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much@robjohn.

Answer (score 8):

Using the integral definition of the arctangent function, we may write $$\arctan{\left(\sin{x}\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sin{x}}{1+y^2\sin^2{x}},$$

thus, transforming the integral into a double integral. Changing the order of integration, we find:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan{\left(\sin{x}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sin{x}}{1+y^2\sin^2{x}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sin{x}}{1+y^2\sin^2{x}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sin{x}}{1+y^2\left(1-\cos^2{x}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+y^2-y^2t^2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\tanh^{-1}{\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)}}{y\sqrt{1+y^2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sinh^{-1}{\left(y\right)}}{y\sqrt{1+y^2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}{(1)}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u}{\sinh{(u)}}\\
&=-\sinh^{-1}{(1)}^2-\int_{0}^{\sinh^{-1}{(1)}}\mathrm{d}u\,\ln{\left(\tanh{\frac{u}{2}}\right)}\\
&=-\sinh^{-1}{(1)}^2-2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\ln{\left(w\right)}}{1-w^2}.\\
\end{align}$$

At this point, the resolution of the last integral in terms of dilogarithms is a straightforward matter.

Comment: This is Excellent! I also enjoyed the previous treatment!

Comment: what a skillful answer!Thank you@David H

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Letting $t=\sin x$, the integral becomes $F(1)$, where $F(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(at)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dx$. Evaluate $F'(a)$.

Comment: thank you,@Lucian. Your answer is same with @integrator.However, all of you solve my question,thank you!