# How do I evaluate integrals of the form: $\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)x^{n}}{1+x^{n+1}} \ dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Few cases have been evaluated:

$n=1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4795632

$n=3:$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801245

I want to know if there is a method to find all related integrals of the form
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)x^{n}}{1+x^{n+1}} \ dx}$$

How do I evaluate these kinds of integrals?

Comment: While `$\tan(x)$` and `$\tanh(x)$` and `$\arctan(x)$` display as $\tan(x)$ and $\tanh(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$, for some reason `$\arctanh(x)$` produces an error: $\arctanh(x)$  (though `$\tanh^{-1}(x)$` as $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ is an alternative option). Hmm... "[e.g., \arctanh, is not native to MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9670/284619)"

Comment: oic, you just used \text{} [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815992/284619)

Comment: For: $n>0$ we have: $$\frac{\gamma  \ln (2)+\ln (2) \ln (4)}{2 (1+n)}+\frac{\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^m \psi \left(\frac{1}{2} (2+m+n+m n)\right)}{2
   (1+m)}}{1+n}$$ where $\psi $ is  digamma function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\artanh}{\operatorname{artanh}}\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\res}{\operatorname{Res}}$If $n$ is even, good luck.

If $n=2m-1$ is odd then we get: $$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\artanh(x)x^{2m-1}}{1+x^{2m}}\d x=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\cdot\frac{x^{2m-1}}{1+x^{2m}}\d x$$But in fact we want to consider: $$J=\int_{-1}^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\cdot\frac{x^{2m-1}}{1+x^{2m}}\d x$$We may extend the logarithmic term to a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$, using the logarithm $\log$ induced by $0\le\arg<2\pi$, cutting on $[0,\infty)$.

Viewing the integrand of $J$ then as a meromorphic function on $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$ we can run a clockwise dogbone contour integral about $[-1,1]$ and pick up a branch-jump of $2\pi i$ in the logarithm as we move from just above $[-1,1]$ to just below. I explain this in more detail in other [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746701). The important point is that this difference gives us $\log()^2-(\log()^2-4\pi^2+4\pi i\log())=4\pi^2-4\pi i\log()$.

The dogbone integral will pick up residues at every pole outside of the strip $[-1,1]$ *including the one at infinity*. Although the integrand uniformly vanishes at $\infty$, there is a nonzero residue! There are **simple** poles at each $2m$th root $\zeta$ of $-1$ and $\frac{(z-\zeta)\cdot z^{2m-1}}{1+z^{2m}}\to\frac{\zeta^{2m-1}}{2m\cdot\zeta^{2m-1}}=\frac{1}{2m}$ as $z\to\zeta$, making the residue evaluation $1/2m$ multiplied with the relevant logarithmic term. **Be careful** with the arguments; it turns out we get pure imaginary terms, and $\log(it)=\begin{cases}\log|t|+\frac{\pi i}{2}&t>0\\\log|t|+\frac{3\pi i}{2}&t<0\end{cases}$ with the branch that I'm using. To catch the residue at infinity, I explain it in the linked posts but recall if $f$ is meromorphic near $\infty$ then $f(z)=f(\infty)\color{red}{-}\res(f;\infty)z^{-1}+o(z^{-1})+\omega(1)$ for large $z$; in our case as $f$ vanishes at $\infty$ we know all the positive $z$-power terms - the $\omega(1)$ part - are zero and $f(\infty)=0$; thus $f(z)=-\res(f;\infty)z^{-1}+o(z^{-1})$ and $\res(f;\infty)=-\lim_{z\to\infty}zf(z)$. It is useful to recall the logarithmic term is continuous (indeed analytic) on $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$ so it plays nicely with limits.

Combining all the above remarks with some algebra, the residue theorem gives us: $$\begin{align}-16\pi i\cdot I&=4\pi^2\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^{2m-1}}{1+x^{2m}}\d x-16\pi i\cdot I\\&=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\res(e^{\pi i(2k-1)/2m})+2\pi i\res(\infty)\\&=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{1}{2m}\log(i\cot(\pi(2k-1)/4m))^2-2\pi i\log(-1)^2\\&=\frac{\pi i}{m}\left[2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\log^2\cot\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{4m}-2\pi i\underset{=0\text{ as $\ln(1/x)=-\ln(x)$}}{\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^m\log\cot\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{4m}}}-\frac{5m\pi^2}{2}\right]+2\pi^3i\end{align}$$So: $$\int_0^1\frac{\artanh(x)\cdot x^{2m-1}}{1+x^{2m}}\d x=\frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac{1}{8m}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\log^2\cot\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{4m},\quad\quad\forall m\in\Bbb N$$

<s>I appreciate that this is rather terse, but I've got to run to a lecture.</s>

Comment: Beautiful result!

Comment: @Zima And numerically verified for small $m$ too, so we can be even more sure that I haven't made any mistakes :) I agree, it is beautiful; moreso is the beauty in how "simple" the method is. Somehow $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$ is all you need to know to compute this integral

Comment: Wonderful result it'll take me like a few college courses to understand why you did what you did though :)

Comment: @EaterofsoapTheVIIth Learn contour integration! Once you know the basics (maybe just even learning the results, without learning the more difficult complex analytic theory) you can see the links I've added to my post for some examples of this specific technique

Comment: I have added some more detail as promised

Answer (score 11):

Integrate by parts to rewrite the integral as follows
\begin{align}
I_n=&\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}\tanh^{-1} x}{1+x^n}dx\\
=& \frac1n \int_0^1 \tanh^{-1} x\ d\left(\ln\frac{1+x^n}2\right)
\overset{ibp}=-\frac1n \int_0^1\frac{\ln\frac{1+x^n}2}{1-x^2}dx
\end{align}
**Odd Case**:  Apply
$$1+x^{2m+1}=(1+x)\prod_{k=1}^m (x^2+2x\cos a_k+1), \>\>\>\>\>a_k=\frac{2k\pi}{2m+1}
$$
along with $\prod_{k=1}^m 2(1+\cos a_k)=1$ and
$ \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}t dt=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$
\begin{align}
I_{2m+1}=& \frac{-1}{2m+1} \int_0^1 \bigg(\ln\frac{1+x}2
 + \sum_{k=1}^m \ln\frac{x^2+2x\cos a_k+1}{2+2\cos a_k}\bigg)\overset{x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}}{\frac{dx}{1-x^2}}\\
 = & \ \frac{\pi^2}{24} -\frac1{2(2m+1)}
 \sum_{k=1}^m\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{(t^2 \tan^2\frac{a_k}2+1})}{t}dt \\
=& \ \frac{\pi^2}{24} +\frac1{4(2m+1)}
 \sum_{k=1}^m \text{Li}_2(-\tan^2\frac{a_k}2)
\end{align}

**Even Case**: Analogous to the odd case
$$ I_{2m} = \frac{\pi^2}{24} +\frac1{8m}
 \sum_{k=1}^{m} \text{Li}_2(-\tan^2\frac{b_k}2),\>\>\>\>\>b_k= \frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2m}
$$
which can be further reduced per the symmetry of $b_k$, as well as the inverse formula
$\text{Li}_2 (-z)+ \text{Li}_2 (-\frac1z)=-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac12\ln^2 z
$, i.e.
\begin{align}
I_{2m} = &\ \frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac1{8m}\bigg[-\frac{m\pi^2}{12}
 -\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac m2]} \ln^2(\tan^2\frac{b_k}2)\bigg]\\
 =&\ \frac{\pi^2}{32}-\frac1{4m}\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac m2]} \ln^2(\tan\frac{b_k}2)
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful result. Your answer reveals how little I know mathematics :)