How to integrate $\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$?
Recently I answered this question. And Math Guy asked me about how will I integrate $$\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$$ ?
Tedious Trig Integral: $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{\frac{\theta (1+\sin^2\theta)\cos\theta}{(1+3\sin^2\theta)(3+\sin^2\theta)}d\theta}$
Since I missed that point, so I deleted my Answer. Also I was unable to answer Math Guy's question on how to integrate $\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$.
Today I want to know that how can I integrate$$\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$$
I first thought of integrating $\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$ by applying the concept of Integration By Parts.
Let's assume that $$I=\int\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))dx$$
$\implies I=\int[\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))×1]dx$
$\implies I=x\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))-\int\left[\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}(\sin(x)))\int 1dx\right]dx$
$\implies I=x\tan^{-1}(\sin(x))-\int\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\sin^{2}(x)}dx$
Note :
$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^{-1}(\sin(x)))=\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin^{2}(x)}$
Now I am facing problem in integrating $$\int\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\sin^{2}(x)}dx$$
Please help me out with the integration of $$\int\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\sin^{2}(x)}dx$$

You can't. There is no closed form in terms of elementary functions.

The answer involves dilogarithms, if done indefinitely. Are there any limits to the integral?

No there are no limits @Gwen

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048045/finding-int-0-frac-pi2-arctan-left-sin-x-rightdx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855517/evaluating-a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficient-in-denominator

Thank you @Martin. I will check them out
