# Find the value of $\frac{(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3})}{1}-\frac{(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7})}{2}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I evaluate:$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)}{1}-\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}\right)}{2}+\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}\right)}{3}-\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\dfrac{1}{15}\right)}{4}+\cdots$$
This series can be found by integrating the following $x^n \arctan(x)$ terms independently:

$$\int_{0}^{i}\dfrac{x^3}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{i}{\left(x^3\arctan(x)-x^7\arctan(x)+x^{11}\arctan(x)-\cdots\right)\ dx}$$

The integral terms are $\dfrac{4}{3}, -\dfrac{22}{840}, \ldots = \left(\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{3}}{4}\right), \left(\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}}{8}\right), \left(\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}}{12}\right) \ldots$
However, I think this evaluation might be completely wrong because
I have evaluated the sequence manually upto the first $18$terms $\simeq 0.77$ and the expected value is $0.8425\cdots$
This was my first attempt at solving the question, Please evaluate the summation in the correct way :)

Comment: So, is your ultimate goal computing $$ \int_{0}^{i}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\arctan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=i\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\operatorname{artanh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, $$ rather than the series? You might want to avoid the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No, I know that $artanh(x)=i\arctan(x)$. I only want the correct way to evaluate the series.

Comment: The result $0.8425$ was taken from:(https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801245), where it was proved that the integral was equal to:$(\frac{\pi^2}{8} -\frac{ln^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)}}{2})\simeq\ 0.8425\cdots$

Comment: The series can also be rewritten as $$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2k-1}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^{4n}}{1-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log 2 - \log(1+x^4)}{1-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{4x^3}{1+x^4}\operatorname{artanh}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. \tag{IbP}
\end{align*}

Note that this integral has been covered by the [link provided by OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801245), yielding

$$ = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} - \frac{1}{2} \log^{2}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)
\approx 0.8452908502. $$

The reason OP's numerical computation deviates from this value is simply because the series converges too slowly. Indeed, the error between the partial sum

$$ S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2k-1} $$

and its limit $S_{\infty}$ is of order $\frac{\log N}{N}$. Indeed, the figure below demonstrates the behavior of $S_n$ for $n=1,\ldots,3000$:

[image: Partial sums]

The horizontal gray line represents the value of $S_{\infty}$, and we see that thousands of terms cannot even estimate the value of $S_{\infty}$ within $0.1\%$.

Comment: Note that the inner summation has $2n$ as upper limit, instead of $n$...

Comment: @cjferes, Oops, thank you for pointing out the mistake! Let me fix it quickly.

Comment: Ohh wonderful thank you :)
I still have a few doubts though:
$$.$$
1) What is the software you used to visualize this information?
$$.$$

2) The connection between the integral and sequence was very random. How could one solve/evaluate the series without any knowledge of the related integral?